# CSS: Image appears outside div borders

Tags: css

I am trying to create a **div** containing an image on the left and other contents such as text on the center. When I add a border to the div, the image appears to be outside.

[image]

```
  <div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div style="border: solid black 2px">
    <img width="100px" height="150px" style="float: left;" src="https://karateinthewoodlands.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/default-user-image.png">
    <p>Username</p>
    <p>User Role</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it because of the float property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `flex` instead of `float` the div will stay in the same size as the image.

```
  <div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div style="border: solid black 2px; display:flex">
    <img width="100px" height="150px" src="https://karateinthewoodlands.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/default-user-image.png">
    <div>
      <p>Username</p>
      <p>User Role</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid `float`. Use `flex` instead

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div style="border: solid black 2px; display: flex;">
    <img width="100px" height="150px" src="https://karateinthewoodlands.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/default-user-image.png">
    <div>
        <p>Username</p>
        <p>User Role</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because of the float. Float is not recommended anymore because of these issues sometimes. You can fix it using `overflow: auto` or `clear: both` in the container to fix this problem.

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div style="border: solid black 2px; overflow: auto">
    <img width="100px" height="150px" style="float: left;" src="https://karateinthewoodlands.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/default-user-image.png">
    <p>Username</p>
    <p>User Role</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of float property. What you can do is

```
<div style="border: solid black 2px; overflow:hidden;">
  <img width="100px" style="height:auto;float: left;margin-right: 10px;" src="https://karateinthewoodlands.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/default-user-image.png">
  <p>Username</p>
  <p>User Role</p>
</div>
```

You need to give the parent div `Overflow: hidden;` property and remove the height of the image. You should not fix the height of the image, instead, you should give a max-height property that will prevent an image to go beyond the max-height.
Also I have added `height:auto;margin-right: 10px;` to the img tag which you can edit or remove if not needed.